# Remove audio streams from a .m2ts video file

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg, stream, transcode

I have a video which has 3 audio streams in the file. The first one is English and the other ones are in different languages. How can I get rid of these audio streams without losing the quality of the video and the English stream.
I think ffmpeg should be used but I don't know how to do it.

Video

> Bit rate mode: Variable
>   Overall bit rate: 38.6 Mb/s
>   Chroma subsampling: 4:2:0

Audio

> Format: DTS-HD
>   Compression mode: Lossless

Comment: `ffmpeg -i input.m2ts -map 0:0 -c copy output.m2ts`???

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I found out that there should be two -map commands written. -map 0:0 for the video and -map 0:1 for the audio. One thing I noticed, it encoded faster than I expected.

Comment: `-c copy` is what makes it faster, it literally means copy codecs, don't re-encode

Comment: Oh okay, I get it now. Thank you again for helping me out!